# How to make a button work infinitely and not only once when pressed discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I just learnt how to make a button in discord.js, and I even learnt how to make a cookie counter, but the only problem is that I can only click it once. If I do it again, it doesn't work. My code is:

```
let button = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('cookie')
        .setLabel('0')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)

        let clicker = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            button,
        );
        console.log(button);
        console.log(button.data.label);
```

for the components and

```
        const filter = i => i.customId === 'cookie' && i.user.id === `${interaction.user.id}`;

        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });

        collector.on('collect', async i => {
            if (i.customId === 'cookie'){
                // cookieCount(guildid, messageid);
                const newCookie = Number(button.data.label + 1);
                clicker = new ActionRowBuilder()
                .addComponents(
                    new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('cookie')
                    .setLabel(`${newCookie}`)
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
                );

                await i.update({ embeds: [embed], components: [clicker]})
            }
        });
```

for the update.
Btw I'm relatively new to discord.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `time` option is how long the collector will run in milliseconds. If you remove that option, it should go forever.

```
const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter });
```

Comment: That does fix the issue of it saying failed to create interaction when it is clicked a second time, but now when I click it for a second time, the counter doesn't increase like it is supposed to. So it goes from 0 to 1 when clicked the first time, but the second time it doesnt go from 1 to 2 and so on

Comment: I believe it's because you're still referencing the original button when trying to update the count. You could try `i.componet.label + 1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to have a button that works indefinitely and through restarts of the bot you can create an event called `interactionCreate` and then you can filter that to run only when it's a button interaction.

From that you can check the name of the clicked button then run the correct code for that button. Using the event allows all buttons that the bot has sent to be used.

```js
import { Client, Interaction, InteractionType } from 'discord.js';

client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    if(interaction.type == InteractionType.MessageComponent) {
        if(interaction.customId == 'button_1') {
          // Your code....
        }
    }
});
```